# How to rotate xtick label bar chart plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly

How can I rotate to 90° the team names (x-axis) on Plotly express? They are not turned in the right way.

Here is my code.

```
fig = px.bar(stacked_ratio, y="percent", x="team", color="outcome", 
             color_discrete_map=colors, title="Long-Form Input")
fig.show()
```

Here how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be able to update your x-axis from a figure object with the `update_xaxes` method:

```
fig = px.bar(stacked_ratio, y="percent", x="team", color="outcome", 
             color_discrete_map=colors, title="Long-Form Input")
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=90)

fig.show()
```

You can see all options for `fig.update_xaxes` on the plotly website here: https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/

Comment: I would go for `tickangle = 45`,  but it's all just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 4):

Hi found this piece of code in another forum, it worked for me. Hope this helps!

---

```py
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle= -90)  
fig.show()
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why your code would solve the OP's problem

Answer (score 2):

`Tickangle=90` means that the labels will be rotated by 90° clockwise. If you use the negative sign, you rotate the labels by 90° anti-clockwise, so just the other direction.